# What is the meaning of "command -v lftp >/dev/null 2>&1"?

Tags: linux, bash

I have a script that after a while will run this, but I don't really understand how it works. My understanding for now is that if `command` fails, it will echo something in stderr, but I tried

```
command -v lftp >/dev/null 2>&1
```

and it outputs nothing even if I have `lftp` installed. Can someone explain me what this line does exactly?

```
# check lftp is installed
command -v lftp >/dev/null 2>&1 || {
    echo >&2 "lftp is required. Please install it.      Aborting."
    exit 1
}
```

Comment: When you want to see what a command prints, you have to remove any `>/dev/null 2>&1` because that hides what the command prints.

Comment: Oh, thanks very much ! But I want to understand how the script works at first, not to make it better ...

Comment: I am not telling you how to make the script better! You wanted to SEE THE OUTPUT, I am telling you how to SEE THE OUTPUT!

Comment: Yeah sorry I mistook the output with the exit status, my bad

Answer (score 2):

It looks for `lftp` on the PATH and throws away the location it finds, and/or any errors (it sends them to `/dev/null`, which is like a black hole - data enters it, nothing ever leaves it).

Then, if it failed to find it, it displays the error message and exits the script with an exit code of `1`.

Comment: Ok, and why does he redirect stderr ? The || won't work otherwise ?

Comment: No, it's to avoid confusing the user with irrelevant extra error messages.

Comment: Mmm I don't understand what you mean by that. How redirecting to stdout avoids confusing the user ?

Comment: No, it redirects stderr to /dev/null, so that error messages from `command` don't appear.

Comment: Ok, so without that only stdout would have been redirected to /dev/null ?

Comment: stdin is not affected, or relevant. Only stdout would have been redirected to `/dev/null` without the `2>&1`.

Answer (score 2):

the > /dev/null sends the standard output (file descriptor 1) of the command to the null device (this throws all the output away) then the 2>&1 attaches file descriptor 2 (standard error) to the same place as file descriptor 1 (which was the null device).

This is just a standard way of discarding all the output. The following would have the same effect:

```
... 2> /dev/null 1>&2
```

Note that order is important so:

```
2>&1 > /dev/null
```

would not have the same effect; you would discard standard out but leave standard error attached to the file descriptor of standard out.

The thing to know that helps make sense of it all is that by default in Unix a program starts up with three file descriptors open:
0 = standard in (stdin or, in C++, cin)
1 = standard out (stdout or, in C++, cout)
2 = standard error (stderr or in C++, cerr)

Comment: Thank you for that it makes it clearer, I didn't know the difference :)

Answer (score 2):

`command -v` is the POSIX-standard way to find out what the shell will do to execute a command. If the argument corresponds to a executable, it will print out the path, and exit with successful status. If the argument is nothing that the shell can execute, it will exit with failure.

Since the user is not interested in whatever `command -v` prints, both stdout and stderr are redirected to `/dev/null`, this is done by first redirecting stdout to `/dev/null`, and then duplicating stdout into stderr: `>/dev/null 2>&1`

After that, if the lookup done by `command -v` failed, a list (enclosed in `{}`) is executed. This is done with `||`, which you can read as *the left part succeeds OR execute the right part*.

The list (which is executed if `command -v` fails) outputs a diagnostics message to stderr, and then exits the script with failure:

`>&2` duplicates stderr into stdout, now everything you write to stdout will go to what originally was just stderr.
`exit 1` exits with failure status. Shells use 0 exit status for success, and not 0 for failure.

Comment: OP should have selected this answer.